# How To Change The Domain Name In My Website

Tags: wordpress, web, hosting, google-search-console

I added my web on to google search console.But On The Search Results Dosen't Show The Name.It shows My Hosting Providers Name(Infinty Free)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgPdo.jpg).

I Try It In You tube But I Can't Fix.I'm Expecting Add my Website Name To It.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Site title should be what you want
Go to setting general and Site Title
[check in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gjxg.png)

Comment: I checked It. But I saw Site Title - Cricket News. In The Search Results Shows 'Infinity Free'. How To Fix It.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).